# tensorflow is not working on a conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I created an environment on conda and installed the tensorflow on it, with following the instruction from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda). I check the tensorflow version on my environment with `pip list | grep tensorflow`
 and it returns `tensorflow (1.3.0)`.

but when I want to check tensorflow with python with `import tensorflow as tf` I got the error:`Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.`

Any suggestion how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it by this command:

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow`

from this [post](https://gist.github.com/Jverma/a7344660933c8c3c1ab7)